# UICollectionViewCells inside UICollectionReusableView not being rendered?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a `collectionView` header that has a horizontal `collectionView` inside of it [ the main `collectionView` being vertical ].

The header is rendered out, however, I am not getting the models' count for the horizontal `collectionView`

I have ensured the following;

- Both of the `collectionViews`' `delegate` & `dataSource` are set to
  `self`
- The data is being retrieved
- I am calling `.reloadData()` on both collectionViews on the `.main` queue.

### Header Code

```
private var collectionViewHeader: ExploreTableHeaderView = {
        let view = ExploreTableHeaderView()
        return view
    }()

class ExploreTableHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 16
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        view.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
        view.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        view.allowsSelection = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.register(ExploreCategoryCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Identifier.categoryCell)
        return view
    }()

// Override frame, addSubView etc...
```

### Header Implementation

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.headerCell, for: indexPath) as! ExploreTableHeaderView
        return headerView
    default:
    return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}
```

### DataSource

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == collectionViewHeader.collectionView {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.categoryCell, for: indexPath) as? ExploreCategoryCollectionViewCell {
            let category = self.categories[indexPath.item]
            cell.category = category
            return cell
        }
    } else {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.itemCell, for: indexPath) as? ExploreItemCollectionViewCell {
            let item = self.recentItems[indexPath.item]
            cell.item = item
            return cell
        }
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

### Reload Views

```
private var categories = [Category]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionViewHeader.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    private var recentItems = [Item]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.itemsCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some detail on how you set the delegate and data source?

You said Both of the collectionViews delegate & dataSource are set to self, but I didn't see int the code, so my hypothesis is the self you referred is different for each collectionViews

My hypothesis is you need to set the delegate & data source in this line of code

```
private var collectionViewHeader: ExploreTableHeaderView?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.headerCell, for: indexPath) as! ExploreTableHeaderView
        headerView.collectionView.dataSource = self
        headerView.collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionViewHeader = headerView
            return headerView
        default:
        return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    }
```

edit:
here example code
https://github.com/aiwiguna/CollectionViewReuse

Comment: I set them both in ViewDidLoad() collectionView & headerView.collectionView

Comment: I think you cannot do that in viewDidload(), because you use dequeueReusableSupplementaryView in the func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath),its different instance, do you try the code I share above?

Comment: because you use dequeueReusableSupplementaryView, don't create a new instance for the ExploreTableHeaderView

Comment: @DavidLintin I updated the code, you can check the updated code

Comment: No Effect.  the collectionView is there just no cells.

Comment: Is it because I am dequeuing the header before the data is received??

Comment: wait, I will create some example project

Comment: @DavidLintin I update my post with URL to the example project you can check it out

Comment: Thanks.  why do you set self.headerView = self when its already being cast as a custom view inside the dequeueReusableSupplementaryView method?  Is this something I've missed??

Comment: the code is self.headerView = headerView, its to make a variable of the CustomCollectionReusableView in the VC so u can call reload data for the collectionView inside the CustomCollectionReusableView